# Inno Setup: How can I get the Exception Code of a raised Exception?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have the following function that raises an exception:

```pascal
procedure Test();
var
  WinHttpReq: Variant;
begin
  WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
  try
    WinHttpReq.Open('POST', 'https://tv.eurosport.com/', False);
    WinHttpReq.SetRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    WinHttpReq.Send('');
  except
    MsgBox(GetExceptionMessage, mbError, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

Instead obtaining the error in a string `GetExceptionMessage`, I would like to obtain the error as an integer.

Is this possible?

Comment: I would like to handle the SSL Certificate error and I think relying on a string as a constant is bad practice.

Comment: If there is no way to get the Error Code then I will rely on the string.

Comment: For example: `if ErrorCode = SSL_CERTIFCATE_ERROR then doStuff()` and not `if GetExceptionMessage = 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest: the host name in the certificate is invalid or does not match' then doStuff()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions do not have any code in general. So there's no generic way to retrieve a code from an exception.

In this particular case the exception is based on an OLE automation error, which does have a code. Though, the code is not preserved, when the Inno Setup raises the exception for `IDispatch` interfaces (OLE).

---

What you can do, is to use the `IUnknown` interface. For that you need to:

- define a Pascal-style interface for the [`IWinHttpRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/iwinhttprequest-interface)
- define `CLSID_WinHttpRequest`
- instantiate the object using the [`CreateComObject`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcomobject) (instead of the `CreateOleObject`).
- call the `Send` method defined as `function Send(Body: Variant): HResult`
- check the returned `HResult` for 12038 (ERROR_INTERNET_SEC_CERT_CN_INVALID).

Particularly the first step is a huge and an error-prone task.

---

For examples and details, see:

- `Examples\CodeAutomation2.iss` in your Inno Setup installation.
- [Pascal Scripting: Using COM Automation objects](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptautomation)

---

If you decide to stick with error message comparison, you may try to use the [`FormatMessage` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage) to retrieve the system/localized error message to compare with. See [How i can retrieve the error description for a WinInet error code from delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6605708/850848).

Comment: I was hoping for something simpler, so what do you recommend relying on the string or the integer?

Comment: I don't think it's to relevant as to what I want to do after the exception but nevertheless I will explain. If there is a certificate validation error I will try the same request on HTTP and not HTTPS. On the application I am developing there are rare instances of clients that have support for HTTP but on HTTPS have certificate validation errors.

Comment: Well it matters then. As you can have the `WinHttpRequest` ignore certificate errors, avoiding getting the error in the first place. So you won't have to detect the error.

Comment: Anyway, to answer your question. It's pretty difficult to define the interface correctly. I wouldn't even try.

Comment: I've added one more hint to my answer.